# Echo php in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am having problem getting the php echo to work in jQuery.

```
global $data; // fetch options stored in $data
```

Can you please point me in the right direction, Thanks.

## jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var slidertype = "<?php global $data; echo $data['slider_type']; ?>";
  $('.flexslider').flexslider( {
        animation: "slidertype",
        controlNav: false,
        smoothHeight: true, 
        slideshowSpeed: 7000, 
        animationSpeed: 600,
        start: function(slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
     });
```

## PHP

```
<select id="slider_type" name="slider_type">
    <option value="slide" id="0"></option>
    <option value="fade" id="1"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: did you mean `animation: slidertype` without the quotes?

Comment: as an aside, Try to avoid having an HTML ID attribute start with a Digit. While I believe this is now valid in HTML5, it is still considered a best practice to not do this.

Comment: the slidertype does not work without quote.

Comment: What do you see if you `print_r($data);`? This will show you everything in the `$data` array and verify that it isn't empty.

Comment: result for print_r($data['slider_type']); are fade

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var slidertype = "<?php global $data; echo $data['slider_type']; ?>";
  $('.flexslider').flexslider( {
        animation: slidertype, // Need to reference the var, not a string literal
        controlNav: false,
        smoothHeight: true, 
        slideshowSpeed: 7000, 
        animationSpeed: 600,
        start: function(slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: I think you're confused about what you're asking @user2014114